# CSS selector - Selecting specific tags inside a parent class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Why is it that the CSS selector is not picking only the elements inside the parent class, and its rather picking all the tags in the code. Even though it is mention took look inside ".new1 h1, p" CLASS. Is it possible to apply CSS on selected tags inside a class, or do i need to add additional classes on p, h1 tags.

```css
.new1 h1,
p {
  color: purple;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

<section class="new1">
  <p> Hello </p>
  <h1> Hi! </h1>
</section>

<section class="new2">
  <p> Hello </p>
  <h1> Hi! </h1>
</section>
```

Comment: `.new1 h1` selects `h1` inside *(child of)* `.new1` . `p` alone, selects every p of the document. You also need to filter from the parent : `.new1 p` , but `.new1{}` is enough since `text-align` and `color` are inherited. You need to learn about https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. you should use `>` for that
> 2. `>` will be used when you want a property value to be applied to specific element not for all element.

```css
.new1>h1,
.new1>p {
  color: purple;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

<section class="new1">
  <p> Helloooo </p>
  <h1> Hiiii! </h1>
</section>

<section class="new2">
  <p> Hello </p>
  <h1> Hi! </h1>
</section>
```

Comment: i also found out that  `.new1, h1 p` works perfect. So i need a comma after a parent element to select whatever i want?

Comment: Correct, when you want other elements to have the same property that is where you use `,` to that, I just shared one of the way probably the correct way to fix your problem.

Comment: @Shubham here is another example, the comma separator may not work in this case, so as answered you should use `>` for this: https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/gah1uozs/45/ if you see the fiddle even though I have not used `div` in the css I still get property value added, which is not correct.

Comment: Yes, thanks for letting me know. Never knew that.